# project tango use adb via USB3.0

Tags: android, adb, google-project-tango, tango

I want to use adb connect the project tango via the mini-dock's usb3.0 port . I tried but I failed . Do I have to set some thing in **setting** ? like enable USB3.0 port ? Thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which mini-dock you talking about?
if you are talking about the mini-dock using for charging.
that usb3.0 won't have ADB connection. It is normal USB,
you can plug your usb drive as external storage.

Comment: Does project tango have another mini-dock ?  I don't know it.  :-)  . Yes I have a mini-dock which can use for charging and the mini-dock have a USB3.0 port too , do you mean I can't make a ADB connection via that USB3.0 port ? Thank you for your reply .

Comment: yes, that is the only mini-dock. and unfortunately you can't make any ADB connection through that. it design to be plug for external storage.